# Changes to page are not saved (on page reload)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

```
<div class='wrapper one Stone' id='main'>
<h1>Stone</h1>
<p>Price: $130.00 per Yard</p>
 <?php if($_SESSION[id]) {?> 
<button class="Stonebutton"> Delete Stone</button>
<script>; $(".Stonebutton").click(function(){$(".Stone").remove();}); </script> 
 <?php } ?> 
</div>
```

When im logged in i can see the "Remove Stone" button and when i click it, it goes away but when i reload the page it comes back. Any help? Thanks a bunch!Im also loading this into the html page with a seperate php file using this:

```
fwrite($PlantFile, "\n\n<div class='wrapper one $trimmedname' id='main'>\n<h1>$name</h1>\n<p>Price: $price</p>\n <?php if(\$_SESSION[id]) {?> \n<button class=\"$trimmedbname\"> Delete $name</button>\n<script> \$(\".$trimmedbname\").click(function(){\$(\".$trimmedname\").remove();}); </script> \n <?php } ?> \n</div>\n");

fclose($PlantFile);
```

Also if anyone has a better solution on what to do, im all ears. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Why do you believe DOM mutations are permanent?

Comment: I'm still fairly new to php and jquery. The documentation says `Use .remove() when you want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it. In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed. `

Comment: Yes, but this doesn’t apply permanently. It would be horrible if it did so. If you want permanent changes, you can control the behavior with a [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) entry.

Comment: So what's your conception of what "reloading the page" means, then?

Comment: jQuery is a client side library that only manipulates the loaded html on the client. It doesn't affect anything on the server, so when you reload, you get the original file from the server again. It would be kind of horrible of jquery changed the original file, specially since 100 people could then view and change the files at the same time.

Comment: @glennsl when you click the reload button in the browser.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ah okay. That makes more sense.

Comment: "when you click the reload button in the browser." lol, yeah, I guess technically you are correct :D But what do you think that does? What's the purpose of having a reload button? Why do you click on it?

Comment: To refresh the page. To see if any information has updated.

Comment: @Xufox I have now tried my code with `<div class='wrapper one yoyo' id='main'>
<h1>yoyo</h1>
<p>Price: $45.99</p>
  
<button class="yoyobutton"> Delete yoyo</button>
<script> $(".yoyobutton").click(function(){
 localStorage.setItem("hidden", " ");
 document.getElementsByClassName('yoyo')[0].innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("hidden");}); </script> 
  
</div>` and it doesnt seem to be permanent either.

Comment: Right, which means to ask the server to re-render the page based on the information it's got. You therefore need to also tell the server that the item has been removed, so it won't re-render it .

Comment: @glennsl do you have any links or references that might help me because i have been searching for some and some of them turn out to not be able to help my current situation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're specifically trying to do, but you seem to be missing the fundamentals of how it all fits together. I think something like the [programming tutorials on Khan academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming) could be a good start.

Comment: You’re just unconditionally setting and then getting a `localStorage` property. This doesn’t do anything useful. Use the storage to set whether the element should be visible or not and use `if` statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to properly understand this, you need to understand the life-cycle of a web page.

1. The browser makes a request to the server.
2. The server responds to that request. From the large array of possible responses, we'll assume everything went OK and it responded with a web-page (status code: `200`). Most times (and the case we will consider here), the response is HTML.

Excluding all the things that could go wrong, **a server will always return the same result for the same request**. However, sometimes, that's not enough and that's where we use JavaScript. With JavaScript, we can make changes to the returned HTML, without having to tell the server: create a new page, containing this mod.

`.remove()` is such a JavaScript method. It changes the HTML after it was returned. It removes an HTML element that was part of the initial response, without going back to server and removing the code that generated the element in the first place, during the request.

This means that the page will contain the element again when you refresh the page, because you're making the same request (you're back to step 1).

If web worked the way you seem to expect it to, anyone could open up the console and delete the entire website with a simple line of code:

```
document.body.remove();
```

Luckily, that's not how web works.

Comment: Ooooh. Okay, thank you very much! I understand this a lot better now. I appreciate the help.