# Locally edit Text on Websites - No reset after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

I am wondering if there is a way to locally edit a specific label on a website, so that the label won't change even after the page reloads.

It is possible to edit a value with the Chrome Developer-Tools. But if you refresh the page, all changes will be resetted.

Is there a way to change a value in such a way that it won't change after the page reloads?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: dont reload page . Edit your changes on elements section just after pressing `F12`

Comment: If you're altering the label on the console, all changes are going to disappear. If you have access to the source code, you can do this storing the label somewhere upon changing.

Comment: But you can create a chrome extension that will change this one label on page load every time using javascript, which is weird but it's ok.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changes to page are not saved (on page reload)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46507515/changes-to-page-are-not-saved-on-page-reload)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

- Assign a data-editableId="XXXX" attribute to the labels you want to edit.
- Add some JS to the page that adds click and blur event listeners to every element that has that attribute.
- The onclick function should add the contenteditable="true" attribute to the clicked element. Then you will be able to edit the label.
- The onblur function should get the data-editableId attribute and the text of the element, and send those to a PHP server script via AJAX.
- In PHP you can then update the database or HTML file and change the content. When the page is reloaded the element will have the new text.

Of course, this JS should only be available to you (you can include it only if some admin session variable is set).